# Consulta sobre el concepto de Overriding Methods

Tags: javascript

hago esta consulta porque estoy viendo prototipado en JavaScript y no comprendo bien a que le llaman "Overriding Methods" y no pude encontrar una pagina en español que lo explique de forma clara.

entonces, en palabras concretas y faciles de entender, ¿que es "Overriding Methods"?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta puede ser interesante pero siento que es poco clara y puede ser cerrada, te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta, formulandola mejor

Comment: No estoy muy ducho todavia en este foro, de que manera me recomendarias que la formule mejor?  Creo que es bastante objetiva de todos modos.
Gracias igual por la observacion.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es válida y clara. La sobreescritura de métodos es un concepto universal, no pueden haber múltiples maneras de hacerlo y menos cuando se habla de JavaScript.

Comment: Puedes revisar los siguientes enlaces para que conozcas un poco más la comunidad: [help], [tour], [ask], [answer]

Comment: @GustavoGarcía si, pero yo creo que puede ser cerrada porque no veo una pregunta clara dentro del contexto, "es lo mismo que método constructor?" no me parece la mejor forma de preguntar por la *sobreescritura de métodos*

Comment: @Jorius, podría aplicar lo que dices. En todo caso, sería mejor que el OP cambie esa línea por, ¿Qué es overriding methods? o simplemente sacarla.

Comment: Ahi edite la consulta. Espero se interprete mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding methods significa sobreescritura de métodos y es una técnica de la programación orientada a objetos. Esta técnica consiste en **sobreescribir métodos que han sido heredados** para añadir código extra o simplemente cambiar/extender su funcionalidad.

Imagina que tenemos la función `Hero`:

**Hero**

```
function Hero () {
  this.name = '';
}

Hero.prototype.getPowers = function() {
  return ['Super strength'];
}

Hero.prototype.toString = function() {
  var str = 'Hello, I\'m a superhero and my name is ' + this.name;
  str += '\nThis are my powers:\n\n'
  for(var power of this.getPowers()) {
    str += '- ' + power + '\n';
  }
  return str;
}
```

Como se puede observar, la función `Hero` tiene una propiedad `name` y dos métodos: `getPowers` y `hello`. El método `getPowers` retorna la lista de poderes del héroe y `toString` devuelve un `toString` (heredado de `Object`) personalizado del objeto, mostrando su nombre y sus poderes.

Ahora, tenemos una función llamada `Superman`:

**Superman**

```
function Superman() {
  this.name = 'Clark Kent';
}

Superman.prototype = new Hero();

Superman.prototype.getPowers = function() {
  var powers = Hero.prototype.getPowers();
  powers.push('X-ray vision');
  powers.push('Fly');
  powers.push('Extreme velocity');
  return powers;
}
```

Lo primero que nos damos cuenta al mirar la función `Superman` es que hereda de `Hero`. Esto lo podemos saber por la línea:

```
Superman.prototype = new Hero();
```

Más abajo vemos que **hemos vuelto a definir el método** `getPowers`. Este método, se dice que está **sobreescrito**, ya que sobreescribe el método original de `Hero`. En este método sobreescrito hemos **extendido su funcionalidad** para poder añadir poderes propios de Superman.

Si ejecutamos el código anterior, veremos que lista todos los poderes de `Superman` y no solo el de `Hero`.

**Ejemplo completo**

```js
function Hero () {
  this.name = '';
}

Hero.prototype.getPowers = function() {
  return ['Super strength'];
}

Hero.prototype.toString = function() {
  var str = 'Hello, I\'m a superhero and my name is ' + this.name + '. ';
  str += 'These are my powers:\n\n'
  for(var power of this.getPowers()) {
    str += '- ' + power + '\n';
  }
  return str;
}

function Superman() {
  this.name = 'Clark Kent';
}

Superman.prototype = new Hero();

Superman.prototype.getPowers = function() {
  var powers = Hero.prototype.getPowers();
  powers.push('X-ray vision');
  powers.push('Fly');
  powers.push('Extreme velocity');
  return powers;
}

var clark = new Superman();
console.log(clark.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Con mucha modestia pues la traduccion no es mia, la mejor traducción para **override** es *"re-definir"* un "metodo".

Puesto que un metodo ya tiene su **nombre,** su definicion o implementacion, es decir el codigo y los parametros que lo componen.

La palabra *sobre-escribir* es una traducción literal **desafortunada.** El metodo "overrided",  **supone volver a usar el mismo nombre** ¡no cambiarlo! que es lo que se pretende significar al hablar de sobre-escritura en contraste a insertar.

Lo que cambia en un método *re-definido* son sus parametros, y/o el contenido o bloque del método, para ampliar (mejorar o precisar) su funcionalidad original.

Comment: Hola Creyente, primero que nada, estás contestando una pregunta que tiene más de 5 años, cuando se habla de sobre-ecribir, no se hace referencia al nombre del método, sino al método mismo.

Comment: Esa aclaración que haces *..."no se hace referencia al nombre del método, sino al método mismo"...* está hecha en los párrafos 2 y 4 de mi comentario anterior. Si mencioné el nombre (Identificador que representa al método inequívocamente), fue para dar a conocer las ambigüedades a las que puede conducir una **funesta traducción literal.** Y tienes razón fue hace 5 años, pero nunca es tarde :¬)